# Use bash to create a new file and use variables from previous lines

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a new file within a bash script. However, the new file body is such that it sets a prefix variable in the 1st line, and the next line should use the prefix variable and set their own respective variable. Below is my bash script

```
main() {
    PWD=`pwd`
    touch $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo prefix=$PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install > $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo exec_prefix=${prefix} >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo includedir=${prefix}/include >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo libdir=${prefix}/lib64 >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo 'Name: PPPS Client Library' >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo 'Description: Intel Packet Processor Pipeline Simulators Client library' >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo 'Version: 0.6.7.1' >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo Cflags: -I${includedir} >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
    echo Libs: -L${libdir} -lppps_client -lpcap >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
}
main
```

The file that is generated is unable to use the prefix set in the first line. Below is the output of the file generated.

```
prefix=/home/aman/fxp_simulator/sdk/install
exec_prefix=
includedir=/include
libdir=/lib64
Name: PPPS Client Library
Description: Intel Packet Processor Pipeline Simulators Client library
Version: 0.6.7.1
Cflags: -I
Libs: -L -lppps_client -lpcap
```

However, the file should have the below contents

```
prefix=/sandbox/1085236/fxp_simulator/sdk/install
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${prefix}/lib64

Name: PPPS Client Library
Description: Intel Packet Processor Pipeline Simulator's Client library
Version: 0.6.7.1
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lppps_client -lpcap
```

Comment: `echo prefix=$PWD...` does ***not*** set a variable named `prefix` but rather just prints a line of text that starts with the literal `prefix=`; you'll need to first set `prefix` and then print it, eg, `prefix="$PWD/..." ; echo "$prefix"`

Comment: Btw: I suggest to take a look at [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells).

Comment: _"is unable to use the prefix set in the first line"_ -- the only assignment is on the line `PWD=\`pwd\``. `echo prefix=$PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install` does not do an assignment, it just outputs a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of quotes is wrong and your code has unnecessary repetitions. A corrected and simplified version could be:

```
main() {
    echo "prefix=$PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install"'
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${prefix}/lib64
Name: PPPS Client Library
Description: Intel Packet Processor Pipeline Simulator'\''s Client library
Version: 0.6.7.1
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lppps_client -lpcap' > fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
}
main
```

Within double quotes, variable expansions are performed. They are not performed within single quotes. You can have embedded newlines inside quotes; you don't need so many `echo`s. Note that `PWD` is a shell built-in variable (it is set to the current directory by the shell automatically), so `` PWD=`pwd` ``  is not necessary (unless `PWD` is explicitly assigned a value before calling the function).

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the `prefix=...` into a *file* rather than saving a *variable* with that name.

What you should rather do is something like this:

```bash
PWD=`pwd`
touch $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
prefix=$PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install
echo $prefix > $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
echo exec_prefix=${prefix} >> $PWD/fxp_simulator/sdk/install/ppps_client.pc
```

Additionally, I recommend you to quote arbitrary strings. This way, you avoid having the strings "escape" and actually ran (somewhat like an SQL injection but it's bash )
With your code, that would be

```bash
# either
PWD="`pwd`"
# or
PWD="$(pwd)"
```

Generally speaking, just quote everything with variables just to be on the safe side.